# How to return rows in which there are NaNs for multiple columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Let us assume this is my DataFrame

```
  City    State Country
Name                   
A     NYC     NaN   NaN
B     NaN     NaN   USA
C     NYC     NY    NaN
D     601009  NaN   NaN
E     NYC     AZ    NaN
F     000001  NaN   NaN
G     NaN     NaN   NaN
```

How do I get hold of rows that have NaNs, both in State and Country.
I'm looking for the following output

```
  City    State Country
Name                   
A     NYC     NaN   NaN
D     601009  NaN   NaN
F     000001  NaN   NaN
G     NaN     NaN   NaN
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

use `isnull`:

```
In [133]: wd[wd['Country'].isnull() & wd['State'].isnull()]
Out[133]: 
        City State Country
Name                      
A        NYC   NaN     NaN
D     601009   NaN     NaN
F     000001   NaN     NaN
G        NaN   NaN     NaN
```

or

```
In [135]: wd[wd[['State', 'Country']].isnull().all(axis=1)]
Out[135]: 
        City State Country
Name                      
A        NYC   NaN     NaN
D     601009   NaN     NaN
F     000001   NaN     NaN
G        NaN   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a bunch! Do I have to do anything to close this question?

Comment: @AkashNandi, you can accept the answer. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) should help.